# Migrating from OS Commerce to...?

Tags: oscommerce

I am looking to move on from OS Commerce. 1,500 products and many years, it's time. I would prefer to migrate to BV Commerce. Is that possible? Is there a similarly reliable store as BV that can import from OSCommerce? I'd like customer info, products, price, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to probably contact BV commerce and ask them directly.

There is also a tool from Magento which allows you to migrate from osCommerce to magentocommerce. http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/114/os-commerce-import

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose [ZenCart](http://www.zen-cart.com/). It is based on ZenCart, but a lot more modert and is constantly improving.